# saltstack remove part of configuration

Tags: state, salt-stack

I deployed this state, this is all installed.  I do not want to remove all of it only `php5`.  How can I do this with salt leaving the other tools in tact?

```
webserver_stuff:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - pkgs:
      - apache2
      - php5
      - php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need pkg.purged.

This makes sure the package is not installed anymore. You can make an extra state for it like this:

```
webserver_stuff:
  pkg.installed
    - pkgs:
      - apache2
      - php5
      - php5-mysql

php5:
  pkg.purged: []
```

Comment: ok, this worked and also how can I remove just a port from the apache configuration, i.e. port 443 using saltstack ?

Comment: You may be able to use salt.states.file.line to remove the line from the file (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.line). This can take a fragment of a string or a regex, then do something based on its mode (ensure, replace, delete, insert).

Comment: I would make two different configuration files for Apache. one iwth and one without port 443. By using the one without port 443 it will be removed.